# looping trough array rendering jsx element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to use wrapper inside jsx component. I want in props item to call function that will decide where add to props two callback function or not. But it gives me promise in return. So I cant call these callbacks in a child component(. What should I change to make it works?

```
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="aplication">
                <Menu isLogined={(this.state.user)? true: false}
                      fullName={this.state.user && this.state.user.name + " " + this.state.user.surname}/>
            <div className="container border">
                {(this.state.isLoading)? (<p>Loading...</p>)
                    : this.state.postList.map((post, i)=>
                        (<Post title = {post.title}
                              post= {post.text}
                              handlers={this.getHandlers(post.user_id)}
                        />))
                }
                <NewPostForm add={this.add}/>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

```
    async getHandlers(postUserId) {
        let result = await fetch('/api/user');

        if(result.ok) {
            let serverUser = await result.json();
            let handlers = {edit: this.edit, remove: this.remove};

            if (serverUser
                && (serverUser.role == 'admin'
                || serverUser.id == postUserId)) {
                console.log(handlers);
                return handlers;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: An async function always returns a promise. Would be better to make those requests when you load the post data and include the results in your state before you do render

Comment: thank you. I was so full(((

Comment: but I loop through data rendering it(( I dont understend where to call data for specific item(